# Two products on a Single date, Pivot date grouping through gaps

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following sample daily production data as below. The three digit code represent a product.

```
11-Mar-15   LBA
12-Mar-15   LBB
12-Mar-15   PXA
13-Mar-15   GNA
```

When i want to apply pivot i get the above data as below since two products are manufactured on same data

```
3/11/15 LBA
3/12/15 LBB
        PXA
3/13/15 GNA
```

I wanted to show the report based on month
and I also understand that pivot will not be able to group the dates by month if there are any gaps in between. How can i bypass this issue to group dates by Month?

Comment: Add a new column for Date2. If you use `Column C`, the formula in `C2` would be `=if(A2<>"",A2,C1)`

Comment: @OldUgly I don't think your formula suits my purpose.The data2 is a pivot table and data1 is original data. i am not able to group them based on month. I get "Cannot group that selection" error. i have read that, if data2(pivot) has spaces in date column the grouping cannot be done. How can i by pass it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i have formula in date. Hence pivot is not able to group them